# How to include Spring context in third party library method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-bean

I have problem while using **spring boot**. This example of code:

```
@Component
class Bat extends OtherLibrary{

    @Autowired
    public Life var;

    @PostConstruct 
    public void registerBat(){
       OtherLibraryApi api = new otherLibraryApi()
       api.register(new Bat());
    } 

    @Override
    public void onResponce(ResponceVal respVal){
         Life sum = respVal.getLife().add(var);
    }
}
```

Class **Bat** extends third party library class **OtherLibrary**. Thrid party library has abstract method **onResponce** that this library asynchronously call at some method. The problem is that when **onResponce** method is called it doesn't include spring context so autowired field **var** in method **onResponce** has null value.

How can I include spring context in third party library method for using autowired fields ?

Comment: How is the `Bat` class instantiated? Can you share some more code?

Comment: You are Autowiring a primitive type? How would It even work???

Comment: @KarthikR, sorry I forgot about it. I changed my source code.

Comment: That wont work either! How can you `autowire` an Integer? To autowire a bean it must be managed by Spring, and Integers and other primitives are surely not!

Comment: Still its the same. Autowiring would search for eligible beans to plug to this one. Is there a bean that would be suitable for wiring for integer? No. It wont be. You need little more understanding , how beans work and Dependency injection.

Comment: @KarthikR,  you are right. Integer is final and not eligible. Thank you for correcting me. I changed  my source code another time.

Comment: The comment goes lengthy, but to continue. Do following checks and experiment on your own. 1) Check if your component scan scans right package to register beans and autowire 2) Register bean 'Life' with `@Service` or `@Component` and proceed your learning. I would recommend you to read more on to the subject.

Comment: @pleft, I added instantinating of my **Bat** class.

Comment: `api.register(new Bat());` this is definitely wrong (from Spring perspective)! I am not sure but how about passing `this` instead of `new Bat()`? e.g. `api.register(this);`

Comment: @pleft, thank you, it really works. :) Could you answer to my question and I marked it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
api.register(new Bat());
```

this is definitely wrong (from Spring perspective)! I am not sure but how about passing `this` instead of `new Bat()`? This way the Spring managed version of `Bat` class will be registered.

e.g.

```
api.register(this);
```